# Validate similar JSON structure with Cypress?

Tags: javascript, json, unit-testing, cypress, assertion

I got this JSON tree object:

```
let obj1 = {
            "id": 3,
            "estatus": "Abierto",
            "obra": {
                "id": 96,
                "numeroRegistro": "C0001532",
                "ubicacion": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "refDomicilio": "11073",
                }
            }
        }
```

I would like to compare it with another one which has the same structure but different values:

```
let obj2 = {
            "id": 4,
            "estatus": "Cerrado",
            "obra": {
                "id": 96,
                "numeroRegistro": "C0001532",
                "ubicacion": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "refDomicilio": "11073",
                }
            }
        }
```

if I use this assertion on Cypress, this works when the values are similar. But, if they are different, this assertion fails. I just would like to compare the structure (tree) even if the values are different.
`expect(obj1).to.eql(obj2)`

***Error when the values are different:**
expected { Object (id, estatus, ...) } to deeply equal { Object (id, estatus, ...) }*

Do you have any idea which instruction on Cypress I could use to do this? Do you know a way to do so?

Comment: Please be aware that `JSON tree object` is actually just a JavaScript object. JSON is a string.

Comment: You could probably compare the keys. Not the most idea solution, but it's the first one I can think of. `expect(Object.keys(obj1)).to.eql(Object.keys(obj2))`,  `expect(Object.keys(obj1.obra)).to.eql(Object.keys(obj2.obra))`, `expect(Object.keys(obj1.obra.ubicacion)).to.eql(Object.keys(obj2.obra.ubicacion))`. You could probably write a function to do this, checking if the value at a key is an object and recursively checking its keys if it is.

Comment: @Nisala... yes! This first approach sounds very logic. Because, I think Cypress could do this without making a custom function or something like that. Maybe, I use this in order to solve my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I use this library: https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-json-schema/ and cypress for this.

To install the library:

```
$ npm install chai-json-schema
```

Go to `cypress/support/index.js` and import the plugin:

```
import chaiJsonSchema from 'chai-json-schema'; 
chai.use(chaiJsonSchema);
```

Generate your JSON schema using this or something similar: https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-json-to-schema-converter

Then in your test compare the object to the JSON schema:

```
expect(response.body).to.be.jsonSchema(ObjectSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [recursion](https://www.programiz.com/javascript/recursion) and [Cypress docs on comparsion](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Aliases) :

```
compareObjects(obj1, obj2)
function compareObjects(obj1, obj2) {
     for (let key in obj1) {
         if (typeof key === "string") {
             expect(obj1[key]).to.eq(obj2[key])
         } else {
             compareObjects(obj1[key], obj2[key])
         }
     }
}
```